# Exception in thread - User Input

Tags: java

I am in dire need of assistance please. I have a class called Fields and I wish to create an Array of Field objects but when I execute the code below:

```
static Field[] theField;
static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

static void createFields()
{

    System.out.print("Enter the number of fields required: ");
    int numFields = userInput.nextInt();

    theField = new Field[numFields];

    for (int i = 0; i < numFields; i++)
    {

        System.out.print("Enter a name for field " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        String name = userInput.nextLine();

        theField[i].setFieldName(name);

    }

}
```

Then I get the following output and error in the console:

```
Enter the number of fields required: 3
Enter a name for field 1: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TestChart.createFields(TestChart.java:44)
    at TestChart.main(TestChart.java:14)
```

Please can you guys help resolve the error. I have been trying since last night to no avail.

Comment: Which line is `TestChart.java:44`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Line 44 was: theField[i].setFieldName(name); but this question has been resolved. I made a noob error and could not spot it in my code. Thanks again guys!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, while you have an array of Fields, none of the Field objects have been instantiated.  Put the line

```
Field[i] = new Field();
```

before you call

```
Field[i].setFieldName();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was such a noob error and the moment I saw this answer I immediately knew this was what I did wrong. Code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`theField = new Field[numFields]` is just creating array but array is empty so `theField[i].setFieldName(name);` will generate null pointer exception. You need to have the array filled by `Field` objects.

Comment: This was where I got confused and forgot to instantiate the Array elements for the fields. I forgot that with and array of objects you need to instantiate. 

I simply added the following line of code before setting the Field name and it worked.
theField[i] = new Field();

Answer (score 0):

You've created the Field-array (`theField = new Field[numFields];`), but you haven't created the individual `Fields` yet. Let's say you have 3 items, then your array is as follows: `theField = { null, null, null }` resulting in a NullPointerException.

So, add this:

```
if(theField[i] == null)
{
    theField[i] = new Field();
}
```

Right before this line in your for-loop:

```
theField[i].setFieldName(name);
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin... appreciate the feedback and the time you took to answer my question